# Querying index using 'pd.read_sql_query' results in "OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "index": syntax error"

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a very large dataframe file that can not be all loaded into memory, and I need to retrieve many rows by the index, and these rows are non-consecutive, so using pandas.read_csv with skiprows and nrows didn't seem like an effective way to retrieve these rows.

I saw that for my case, a database is probably the best way to to handle my data.

I was able to send my data to a sql database, but I am getting an error when I try to retrieve by index.

The following is a minimal example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///memory.db')

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

data.head(2)


A   B   C   D
0   64  57  97  99
1   58  31  32  43
```

I tried a few queries, which worked fine

```
pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM data', engine)


index   A   B   C   D
0   0   64  57  97  99
1   1   58  31  32  43
2   2   89  56  76  53
3   3   68  13  20  39
4   4   84  34  25  12
5   5   58  10  46  37
6   6   50  85  96  68
7   7   41  55  88  92
8   8   54  72  49  56
9   9   58  20  15  92
10  10  92  20  11  81
11  11  88  6   81  1
12  12  90  90  39  11
13  13  64  84  37  80
14  14  8   82  90  22
```

One thing I noticed that the original index is being set to a seperate column. I read the documentation in to_sql but I couldn't find anything that sets the pandas df index to thq sql index , it says "indexbool, default True
Write DataFrame index as a column. Uses index_label as the column name in the table." but it seems this means that if its not set to true, the index won't be transferred to the db.

Querying by the columns seems to work fine

```
pd.read_sql_query('SELECT A, C FROM data', engine)


A   C
0   64  97
1   58  32
2   89  76
3   68  20
4   84  25
5   58  46
6   50  96
7   41  88
8   54  49
9   58  15
10  92  11
11  88  81
12  90  39
13  64  37
14  8   90


pd.read_sql_query('SELECT A, C FROM data WHERE B=57', engine)

    A   C
0   64  97
```

But selecting from the index column results in an error

```
pd.read_sql_query('SELECT A FROM data WHERE index=2', engine)



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1277                     self.dialect.do_execute(
-> 1278                         cursor, statement, parameters, context
   1279                     )

12 frames
OperationalError: near "index": syntax error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    591 
    592     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 593         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    594 
    595     def do_execute_no_params(self, cursor, statement, context=None):

OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "index": syntax error
[SQL: SELECT A FROM data WHERE index=2;]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

Comment: Index is a keyword, if you want to refer to the column you must use a quoted identifier `"index"`.

Comment: Wow thanks! Is there a sql design philosophy for putting index in quotes?

Comment: SQL has regular and delimited (quoted) identifiers, and keywords. There are non-reserved and reserved keywords. In SQLite INDEX is a reserved keyword: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html, so you cannot use it as a regular identifier.

Comment: Adding to the previous, the non-reserved keywords are keywords in some contexts, but not others, so they can be used as regular identifiers in some contexts.